# Laravel 5.5 - Laravel Passport Correct Grant Type To Use?

Tags: laravel, api, authentication, oauth-2.0, laravel-passport

I have an application where users can register normally via the site and post job vacancies.

I want registered users to be able to post vacancies using my api via a third party multi job posting application i.e. users register on the third party site, they are presented with a form which posts to an api endpoint on my site.

Now my question is how do I implement this using Laravel Passport.

Is the following correct:

1. I create a passport client for the third party application?
2. Provide the third party application with their client id and client secret.
3. When the user submits the form on the third party website they would include their username (email) and password along with the rest of the form data.
4. The third party application makes a request to (http://my-app.com/oauth/token) using the password grant method to request an access token using their client id, client secret, users email and password.
5. If a valid access token is returned then using that token and the form data a second request is made to (http://my-app.com/api/jobs/add) endpoint.

Can someone advise if this is correct grant type to use or is it insecure for registered users to be supplying a third party application login credentials in order to obtain a access token?

What is the correct grant type to use for the above use case?

If I was to use the authorization_grant method, who would be responsible for creating the client - the admin of my-app.com or the registered user of my-app.com?

If its the registered user of my-app.com then does that mean every registered user would have to create a client on my-app.com for the same third party app which wouldnt make sense as the third party app would then end up with multiple client ids so how would they implement the callback url?

This is very confusing.

Answer (score 1):

You are more or less on track except point #3.

Giving access to your users credentials to a 3rd party system isn't a good idea, and may even not be legally acceptable.
Instead provide a url, which can be opened in a popup for the authentication, and return the auth token to the window.opener

You can provide a function for the parent window (window.opener), which accepts a callback to be called on login success/error:

```
var popup = window.open("/someUrl");
popup.onload = function(){
   popup.onLogin(onLoginSuccessCallback, onLoginErrorCallback);
};
```

or the parent window can have a function which you can call from within the popup:

```
window.opener.loginCallback(token);
```

Comment: so basically you are saying the user should authenticate using a form from my own app which would return an access token. I've never come across any authentication api like this before? This method would not appear to be seamless to the end user.

Comment: Yes it isn't ideal but this is how the login with Facebook, Google account, etc is implemented. I think most users will be used to this kind of authentication.

Comment: is this not the same as using the authorization_grant method: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/passport#requesting-tokens

Comment: It is possible that I misunderstood your situation, but from your description it looks you want to allow users registered in your system to authenticate via 3rd party api client.
If this is correct, the approach you suggest will expose their credentials to the 3rd party, which isn't acceptable in most cases.
If one entity owns both the API and client, it won't be a problem.

Comment: Yes that is correct. I want to be able to authenticate users registered in my system via a third party system which consumes my api. E.g. Users is registered on my system. They then register on a third party system which consumes my api. From the third party system I need to be able to authenticate the user posting to my system. I can only think of the password grant method to make this feasible but as you say this exposes users password to the third party. I dont quite understand the authorize grant method and I doubt if that would be suitable in my use case. Any other ideas?

Comment: the following is an example where a third party submit to an api end point. You can see they are posting by including the users email and password: https://integrations.broadbean.com/hc/en-us/articles/213852305-XML-Submission-Example-

Comment: You should probably consult the stakeholders of your system if this is acceptable or not. The question isn't purely technical it depends also on your local regulations, f. e. the upcoming GDPR may be a problem if you are located in EU.

Comment: what if I introduced a unique posting key for all users. When using the password grant method, the username and password would belong to the third party application who would also be users in my application. The third party application can set themselves up as a client. Users can then post to my end point using a form on the client application by including their posting key. In this scenario users would be responsible for providing the third party application their posting key.